# Iranian Citizen with layover in Cuba: transit visa required?

Tags: visas, transit, cuba, iranian-citizens, bahamas

I am an Iranian Citizen. I am traveling from Iran to Havana, Cuba. Then from Havana, I am traveling to Freeport, Grand Bahama. I have a work permit for the Bahamas. My flight from Tehran to Havana is with Aeroflot. My flight from Havana to Freeport is via a different ticket and on BahamasAir.

Given all of the above, is a transit visa required for Cuba?

Comment: What is your citizenship?
Are both flights booked on the same ticket?

Comment: I AM IRANIAN CITIZENSHIP.AND NO DIFFERENT FLIGHTS DIFFERENT TICKET

Answer (score 2):

A visa is not required.

```
Information as of  23MAY16 / 1743 UTC
National Iran (IR)              /Embarkation Iran (IR)
Transit Cuba (CU)               /Destination Bahamas (BS)
ALSO CHECK DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW

Cuba (CU)

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
time of 72 hours.
- Passengers are allowed to leave the airport.
Warning:
- Neither visa exemptions nor Tourist Card (Tarjeta del
Turista) facilities are applicable to those holding foreign
passports stating Cuba as place of birth. They will be
considered Cuban nationals, unless holding a document signed
by the Cuban Ministry of Foreign Affairs, proving withdrawal
of their Cuban citizenship.
```

See for instance https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm

Comment: So i can trust you.

Comment: @Amir You will need to show your second airline ticket to Aeroflot when you check in to the first flight, so that they know you are transiting.